# How can i print php code by call url?I tried by file name but i want to print by url

Tags: php, html, printing, echo

I am trying to print php code on web page by using my URL. I know by file name i can print php code using "show_source('filename.php');" but i want to print code by URL, not by file.

I tried:-

```
<?php
show_source("http://URL.com/index.php");
?>
```

I also tried this code:-

```
<?php
    $c = curl_init('http://URL.com');
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //curl_setopt(... other options you want...)

    $html = curl_exec($c);

    if (curl_error($c))
        die(curl_error($c));

    // Get the status code
     $status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($c);

    I also tried this code:-

    $html = file_get_contents('https://www.URl.com');
    print_r ($html) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If the web server is configured correctly, it should be impossible to do what you are trying to do.

A correctly configured web server will only send content after PHP has processed it. If the web server is sending raw PHP when a `.php` file is requested, it is misconfigured. If you are trying to view your own PHP files from a server you control, you can try making a copy of the PHP files and changing the extension to `.phps`, which the server should send as raw PHP code. Note that this will expose the PHP source to the web, which could present a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Squidward already mentioned, this should not be possible. Otherwise this would be a major security breach since you can store passwords for databases in the PHP files.

A possible solution for your problem would be that you create a REST API on the second server and there you have a function that gets the content of a specific file and returns it in JSON.

But ensure that you don't pass any critical data as passwords or user-data in it.